# css text shadow

Tags: css, styles

I'm working on a website and I want to add some shadow to my text, is there an easy way to do this using only css? i tried placing a darker clone of the text under it, but that would be hard on different sizes.

Comment: I want to point out text-shadow property is not working previous versions of IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using the **CSS3** `text-shadow` property. The general format for specifying this is:

```
text-shadow: *left-offset* *top-offset* *blur-distance* *color*;
```

Example Usage:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #000000;
```

You can create multiple shadows by separating their definitions with commas:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #000000, -2px -2px 1px #111111;
```

Older versions of IE do not support this property, though; you need to use a `filter`:

```
filter: DropShadow(Color=#000000, OffX=2, OffY=2);
```

Where you replace the values with whatever your preference is.

**Note:** The answer to your question can be found quite easily using the great search engine [Google](http://www.google.com). Please try that next time before asking a question.

**Another note:** You really don't have to mention that the website you're working on is an adult website. It's completely irrelevant and might even be a bit dislikable to some users.

Welcome to Stackoverflow, though! I hope that helped!

Comment: @LifeKnife If it works for you, click on the green tick next to the answer to mark it as "accepted."

Comment: Don't tell people to search Google for the answer. SO is meant to be THE trusted repository of answers... even Google knows that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css text-shadow any times you want on a text:

```
text-shadow:1px 0px 2px grey, -1px 0px 2px grey, 0px 1px 2px grey, 0px -1px 2px grey;
```

will create a shadow whole around the text.